# MYSQL filtering conditionally on first 2 characters

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, postal-code

I have a table of Outcodes (in the UK, the first part of postcodes/zipcode) for example
id,outcode
1, AB1
2, AB2... and so on
27, AL1
28, AL2...and so on
52, B1
52, B2
52, B3
61, BA1
etc. 
I am trying to get a list of unique first parts of the outcode so

AB,
AL,
B,
BA1
The issue is that in the UK the first part of the postcode can be 1 OR 2 letters so AB = Aberdeen, B = Birmingham etc, then a number.
The table consists of id, outcode and some other arbitrary information.
I have managed to get the first part with this code if its 1 letter then a number:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(outcode,1,1)) as outcode
FROM outcodepostcodes
WHERE SUBSTRING(outcode, 2, 1) * 1 > 0
```

and by changing the query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(outcode,1,2)) as outcode
FROM outcodepostcodes
WHERE SUBSTRING(outcode, 2, 1) * 1 = 0
```

I get all the double letters, but i would like ideally is to have a single query to list both other wise I am going to have to do 2 queries and merge the arrays.
 I'm pretty sure its an if statement somewhere but cant get it to work...
Thanks in advance
Keith

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: Thought I did that with line 2 and 4, but will give it a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE WHEN` clause can do the trick :

```
select DISTINCT(case when SUBSTRING(outcode, 2, 1) * 1 > 0 then SUBSTRING(outcode,1,1)
                     else SUBSTRING(outcode,1,2) end) as outcode

from outcodepostcodes
```

Answer (score 0):

*Another response from my side.*

```
with s1 as (select *,
replace(replace(replace(value,1,''),2,''),3,'') rp from series),
s2 as (select *,row_number() over (partition by rp) rn from s1)
select value from s2 where rn = 1
```

*you can use multiple replace function based on your data set.*

[result](https://dbfiddle.uk/AALdwGUX)